# In which contexts are livestock destroyed?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In which contexts are livestock destroyed?

A display about the impacts of the 2009 Black Sunday bushfires included

> Significant amounts of hay and silage destroyed
>
> 250+ beef and dairy cattle destroyed or required emergency slaughter
>
> Numerous wildlife required emergency slaughter

Wiktionary has a definition of destroyed, but says it's for euphenasing animals.

Although Australia does eat kangaroo, we don't eat all kind of wildlife, so I assume the meaning of "slaughter" for the wildlife was killing, as opposed to killing for the purposes of consumption. Therefore, I assume that "emergency slaughter" implies the animals were being euphenased.

Would I be correct in concluding that the fire directly killing cattle is being described by the word "destroyed"? If so, why would that word be used instead of "killed"? Is it used to couch it in terms of an economic loss?

Comment: You are correct. Because the cattle are stock, the word destroyed is used to reflect they are an owned 'item'. Slaughter is used where human decision was made to cause the destruction of the stock for various reasons, such as severe burning, loss of limbs etc

Comment: *destroyed or required emergency slaughter* is using "destroyed" to mean "killed by the fire", not "euthanized".   It would have been slightly clearer to say *killed by the fire or required emergency slaughter*, but the writer probably didn't think of the "euthanized" meaning when writing the piece.  (And, as suggested, "destroyed" implies economic loss, and it also euphemises things a bit.)  (And we definitely need to emphemize euthanizing.)

Comment: @HotLicks: is "emphemize" an intentional misspelling of "euphemize," or an example of Muphry's Law?

Comment: @sumelic - It's another casualty of the fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the meaning of "destroy" here is the first one in http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/destroy: 
"End the existence of (something) by damaging or attacking it." It refers to the animals that were killed by the fire itself.

"Destroy" in that sense is an inclusive word for *all* the effects of the fire - not just the "damage" to the animals and their food supply (hay and silage) but also to buildings, farm machinery, etc.

I would assume that "emergency slaughter" meant killing injured animals quickly by the most humane method that was practical in the circumstances, rather than prolonging their suffering from burns, smoke inhalation, etc. Beef cattle killed in that way could not be used for human food (assuming the food regulations in Australia and the UK are similar), and dairy cattle are not intended to be killed for human food in any case, because their meat is of relatively low quality.

The usual term for "killing a farm animal for meat" in British English is "slaughter", and the place where it is done is a was traditionally called a "slaughterhouse", though it is now often called by the French term "abattoir".

"Destroy" is also used as a synonym for "euthanize", referring to killing animals which become too ill or too old to have a good quality of life. (In the UK, "put down" is often used instead of "destroy" in that sense.) That meaning would imply that the killing was carefully planned in advance and carried out by the most appropriate humane method, which doesn't seem consistent with what happened in a bush fire.